# Best Practices for Proxmox Backup Server(local or SAN)

Tags: backup, proxmox

I'm looking for some advice on optimizing my Proxmox Backup Server setup.

Here's my current setup:
I have three Proxmox hosts, each connected to a SAN via iSCSI with dual fiber switches.
Additionally, I have a dedicated Proxmox Backup Server with a local disk setup in RAID Z configuration, totaling 6TB of storage.
The PBS is equipped with two NICs, both connected to a switch.
I'm thinking of instead having another SAN via fiber switches for PBS but I don't know if that would be beneficial.

My main question is:
What would be the best practice for configuring the PBS for optimal backups?
I'm particularly interested in understanding which option would provide faster backup speeds for my Proxmox hosts. Has anyone had experience with similar setups or insights to share?

Thanks